# Accessing elements with offsets in Python's for .. in loops

Tags: python, loops

I've been mucking around a bit with Python, and I've gathered that it's usually better (or 'pythonic') to use

```
for x in SomeArray:
```

rather than the more C-style

```
for i in range(0, len(SomeArray)):
```

I do see the benefits in this, mainly cleaner code, and the ability to use the nice `map()` and related functions. However, I am quite often faced with the situation where I would like to simultaneously access elements of varying offsets in the array. For example, I might want to add the current element to the element two steps behind it. Is there a way to do this without resorting to explicit indices?

Comment: Note that range(0, len(SomeArray)) is equivalent to the more usual range(len(SomeArray)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way to do this in Python is:

```
for i, x in enumerate(SomeArray):
    print i, x
```

The [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) generator produces a sequence of 2-tuples, each containing the array index and the element.

Comment: But how would I access previous / subsequent elements in one iteration of the loop?

Comment: Inside the loop, you can access SomeArray[i-1] or SomeArray[i+1].

Comment: `SomeArray[i-1]`? But you might want to explain what you're actually doing

Comment: Since you have the index of the current element in `i`, you can access elements around it by adding or subtracting some offset from `i`, and accessing the element at that position.

Answer (score 6):

List indexing and zip() are your friends.

Here's my answer for your more specific question:

> I might want to add the current element to the element two steps behind it. Is there a way to do this without resorting to explicit indices?

```
arr = range(10)
[i+j for i,j in zip(arr[:-2], arr[2:])]
```

You can also use the module [numpy](http://www.scipy.org/) if you intend to work on numerical arrays. For example, the above code can be more elegantly written as:

```
import numpy
narr = numpy.arange(10)
narr[:-2] + narr[2:]
```

Adding the nth element to the (n-2)th element is equivalent to adding the mth element to the (m+2) element (for the mathematically inclined, we performed the substitution n->m+2). The range of n is [2, len(arr)) and the range of m is [0, len(arr)-2). Note the brackets and parenthesis. The elements from 0 to len(arr)-3 (you exclude the last two elements) is indexed as [:-2] while elements from 2 to len(arr)-1 (you exclude the first two elements) is indexed as [2:].

I assume that you already know list comprehensions.

Comment: yep I do know list comprehensions. haven't really used them though. zip() looks like another nice solution, thanks!