# How to get the previous element when using a for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Python - Previous and next values inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011938/python-previous-and-next-values-inside-a-loop)
>   [python for loop, how to find next value(object)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929039/python-for-loop-how-to-find-next-valueobject)

I've got a list that contains a lot of elements, I iterate over the list using a `for` loop. For example:

```
li = [2, 31, 321, 41, 3423, 4, 234, 24, 32, 42, 3, 24, 31, 123]

for i in li:
    print(i)
```

But I want to get the element before `i`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323750/how-to-access-previous-next-element-while-for-looping) [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281752/accessing-elements-with-offsets-in-pythons-for-in-loops) [links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops)

Answer (score 43):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for previous, current in zip(li, li[1:]):
    print(previous, current)
```

or, if you need to do something a little fancier, because creating a list or taking a slice of `li` would be inefficient, use the [`pairwise` recipe from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

```
import itertools

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

for a, b in pairwise(li):
    print(a, b)
```

Comment: +1 for the itertools answer, not the first. The first is fine if the list is small, but if the list is really large, creating a copy would be inefficient.

Answer (score 27):

Just keep track of index using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) and get the previous item by index

```
li = list(range(10))

for i, item in enumerate(li):
    if i > 0:
        print(item, li[i-1])

print("or...")

for i in range(1, len(li)):
    print li[i], li[i-1]
```

Output:

```
1 0
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 4
6 5
7 6
8 7
9 8
or...
1 0
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 4
6 5
7 6
8 7
9 8
```

Another alternative is to remember the last item, e.g.

```
last_item = None
for item in li:
    print(last_item, item)
    last_item = item
```

Answer (score 24):

Normally, you use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) or [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-range) to go through the elements. Here's an alternative using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip)

```
>>> li = [2, 31, 321, 41, 3423, 4, 234, 24, 32, 42, 3, 24, 31, 123]
>>> list(zip(li[1:], li))
[(31, 2), (321, 31), (41, 321), (3423, 41), (4, 3423), (234, 4), (24, 234), (32, 24), (42, 32), (3, 42), (24, 3), (31, 24), (123, 31)]
```

the 2nd element of each tuple is the previous element of the list.

Comment: Yes, this does work, but if your list is really large, do you really want to take the performance hit of creating a second really large list (with `li[1:]`)?

Comment: I already said its an alternative. Of course if the list is REALLY large, then don't use this method. simple as that.

Answer (score 10):

Simply keep track of the previous value using a separate variable.

```
j = None
for i in li:
    print(j)
    j = i
```

Comment: Why isn't this favored over the zip and itertool solutions? It's way more readable.

Answer (score 3):

An option using the `itertools` recipe from [here](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import tee
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

for i, j in pairwise(li):
    print(i, j)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop counter as an index. (Be sure to start at 1 so you stay in range.)

```
for i in range(1, len(li)):
  print(li[i], li[i-1])
```

Answer (score -3):

```
li = [2,31,321,41,3423,4,234,24,32,42,3,24,,31,123]

counter = 0
for l in li:
    print l
    print li[counter-1] #Will return last element in list during first iteration as martineau points out.
    counter+=1
```

Comment: You're wrong about an exception being raised the first iteration. `alist[-1]` is the last element of the list. Doesn't sound like you tried running it yourself -- not worth a downvote, though.

Comment: Thank you - I learned something today.  :-)