# Get value from previous group in for group in groupby

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I create a groupby data frames like this:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date) + pd.to_timedelta(df.Hour, unit='h')
grouped = df.set_index('Datetime').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=horizon))
```

However, I would like to be able to print the first row of the current group in the loop and the last row of the previous group in the list grouped[group-1]. The idea is to get something like this:

```
for name, group in grouped:
    print("first row of the current group")
    print("last row of the previous group in the loop")
```

And if its the first group in grouped, then only print the first row of the current group.

Does anyone have idea on how to do this? I have formulated as general so I could apply it for something a little bit different but that has the same idea behind.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try assigning the current group to a name so you have access to it on the next iteration? - `previous = group`?

Comment: Not really actually because I have names for my groups and they are not indexed like a list. I cannot treat them like they are treated in the example on the other post like ` if index < (l - 1) `. In my case, the index would be a name and is a datetime index.

Comment: `for k,group in grouped:...; ...; prev = group`. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/4002644/2823755](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4002644/2823755)